# Can you edit a instancing collection in Blender 2.8?

Tags: instances, collections

I want to instance a collection a few times.
But when I want to change something I have to go back to the original collection which is not visible if i want to also see the instanced collection so editing the original collection works really slow.

So I was wondering if there is a way to instance a collection (or group of objects if those still exist) where you could edit every instance and it changes every instance and original collection.

Comment: you can try to use Quick Instance addon